# open external file through wave.open in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using wave.open to open file , if i give local path

```
async def run_test(uri):
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
     wf = wave.open('test.wav', "rb")
```

then it is working but if i give external path it is not working

```
async def run_test(uri):
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
     wf = wave.open('http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/test.wav', "rb")
```

getting this error :

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
> 'http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/test.wav'

Comment: what makes you think `wave.open` works across `HTTP`? As the plain file `open`, it operates on local files only (or network ones if mounted of course, but that's an OS issue)

Comment: @Pynchia Maybe they're an ex-PHP developer, where [file operations (dangerously enough) can work with http etc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php). It's not an entirely unreasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, `wave.open()` doesn't know anything about HTTP.

You'll need to download the file first, e.g. with `requests` (or `aiohttp` or `httpx` since you're in async land).

```
import io, requests, wave

resp = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/test.wav')
resp.raise_for_status()
bio = io.BytesIO()  # file-like memory buffer
bio.write(resp.content)  # todo: if file can be large, maybe use streaming
bio.seek(0)  # seek to the start of the file
wf = wave.open(bio, "rb")  # wave.open accepts file-like objects
```

This assumes the file is small enough to fit in memory; if it's not, you'd want to use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer now i'm getting this error :  bio.write(resp.body)  # todo: if file can be large, maybe use streaming and AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body can you please let me know how to resolve this issue, max file size will be around 2 MB

Comment: My bad. It's `resp.content`. Fixed :)